# show names against nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Can anyone tell me how to show the **name** of a node in the graph viewer in the same way that is shown at the demo site: http://console.neo4j.org/

Here it shows **Neo** against node 1 instead of only the node id.  I'm creating nodes through the admin interface - ie. not in the same way as in the example on the site at the top of the page titled 'Graph Setup'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do this in the data browser part of the admin interface, you can configure "styles". Within the style, you can configure filters for certain types of nodes to have different styles and markers (circles, rectangles, font size). It's a little clunky but it's usable to play with the data.

I took a screenshot of some of my chess database as an example (I set the FEN position property to be the node label):
[image]

Comment: Thanks Wes.  I've just tried this and it works as you said.  I clicked Styles, changed the Label value from {id} to {name} (all my nodes have a 'name' attribute'), saved the style profile and whet back to the diagram which automatically refreshed.

Comment: @dubs Peter Neubauer posted a video today that goes through a lot of the admin stuff. Check it out: https://vimeo.com/58016492

Answer (score 2):

A node does not have a name, unless you give it a name property.

The graph viewer in the admin tool can not to my knowledge display anything but the node ID.

I recommend [Neoclipse](https://github.com/neo4j/neoclipse), a tool that can be installed as a plugin in Eclipse, or downloaded as a standalone program.  It will display your nodes with plenty of details.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I'll certainly be checking out Neoclipse.

Comment: Had to mark Wes's response as the answer as I tried it and it does seems to work!  Neoclipse looks good though and I think it will certainly come in useful - thanks.